# What are the prime characteristics of Behavior Driven Development?

Tags: properties, bdd, characteristics

These days I am hearing a word frequently - BDD or Behavior Driven Development.

So I want to know what are the prime characteristics of BDD and how it differs from traditional programming?

Thanks

Comment: The new question by me might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399485/understanding-behavior-driven-development-bdd

Answer (score 1):

Did you at least google it?) prime characteristics are easy to find stuff... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development

Comment: Yup ---------- I read them but here @ Stack many thinktanks roam around, so they can elaborate it further for easy understanding :)

Comment: Better scenario is to feed such pros with narrowed questions )

Comment: Suggest me how can we narrow it? I will change accordingly

Comment: Given the quote "BDD is a second-generation, outside-in, pull-based, multiple-stakeholder, multiple-scale, high-automation, agile methodology. It describes a cycle of interactions with well-defined outputs, resulting in the delivery of working, tested software that matters.": which parts are least clear? which parts are most interesting? Ask questions about those things.